# Error, Cronjob execution is not working ubuntu

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to implement a simple cron job which should work on two scripts once a day at a certain time. I've refered to this tutorial
https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-use-cron-to-schedule-scripts.html

But it doesnt seem to work.

My cronjob file:

```
MAILTO="my@email.com"
0 4 * * * wget -q -0 - "http://example.com/myscript.php"
```

I'm using DigitalOcean Ubuntu Server with Serverpilot & Wordpress

Comment: it mean cron will call those url at certain time. Could you tell me what is your expectation from this cron?

Comment: When it calls this url, the script will be executed and store data in a file. But that doesnt work. Also I'm not getting any emails

Comment: are you sure `myscript.php` works?

Comment: yes, I'm constantly using it but just want to automate it now

Comment: I just got emailed this:  wget: invalid option -- '0'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options. Any ideas ?

Comment: please check your cron again, you use `-0` or `--0`

Comment: I used -0 but I'm not sure, is it a zero or a capital o ? Changed it to Capital o(O) now...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it. I used a zero instead of a O and now I get the email with the report.